# git attributes filter, determine file type from shebang

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-filter

I am using [git attributes and filters](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for auto-formatting before `diff` and `add`.

I have a filter for `*.[ch]`, and another for `*.py`.

I have a number of python scripts that lack a suffix in their filename. These always have a shebang as their first line.

Is it possible to trigger a clean filter based on the content of a file? I'd typically try to parse for something like `^#!.*python.*`.

Comment: No. Like [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) works on **filename patterns**: "*gitattributes - Defining attributes per **path***" … "*A `gitattributes` file is a simple text file that gives `attributes` to **pathnames**.*" Emphasize mine

Comment: Perhaps you could implement something yourself defining a filter for omnipattern `*` and checking the content in the filter. But that could be slow.

Comment: Bummer. Setting the `diff` attribute for various filetypes is really useful to activate custom hunk headers (which are shown in `git diff` and used for scoping in `git log -L:<funcname>:<file>`); Git already has built-in patterns for many programming languages, but many scripts do not use a file extension, as the shebang is authoritative. That's a surprising gap, as Git has its roots in the Unix culture. Does anybody know whether the Git team is already aware of this? Is there an open issue?